# SSH on Linux: Disabling host key checking for hosts on local subnet (known_hosts)

Tags: linux, caching, ssh, ssh-keys

I work on a network where the systems at an IP address will change frequently.  They are moved on and off the workbench and DHCP determines the IP they get.

It doesn't seem straightforward how to disable host key caching/checking so that I don't have to edit ~/.ssh/known_hosts every time I need to connect to a system.

I don't care about the host authenticity, they are all on the 10.x.x.x network segment and I'm relatively certain that nobody is MITM'ing me.

Is there a "proper" way to do this? I don't care if it warns me, but halting and causing me to flush my known_hosts entry for that IP every time is annoying and in this scenario it does not really provide any security because I rarely connect to the systems more than once or twice and then the IP is given to another system.

I looked in the ssh_config file and saw that I can set up groups so that the security of connecting to external machines could be preserved and I could just ignore checking for local addresses.  This would be optimal.

From searching I have found some very strong opinions on the matter, ranging from "Don't mess with it, it is for security, just deal with it" to "This is the stupidest thing I have ever had to deal with, I just want to turn it off" ... I'm somewhere in the middle.  I just want to be able to do my job without having to purge an address from the file every few minutes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 99):

This is the configuration I use for our ever-changing EC2 hosts:

```
maxim@maxim-desktop:~$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host *amazonaws.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keypair1-openssh
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keypair2-openssh
        User ubuntu
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

This disables host confirmation `StrictHostKeyChecking no` and also uses a nice hack to prevent ssh from saving the host identify to a persistent file `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null` note that as an added value I've added the default user with which to connect to the host and the option to try several different identify private keys.

Comment: Wow, that /dev/null hack is brilliant.  I always forget how obviously simple things can be on linux.  Thank you.

Comment: If that solution works for you please accept a valid reply as answer to this question, please remember the other people will be visiting this question page. If something still does not work for you please post another question in the comments.

Comment: If I set the UserKnownHostsFile to /dev/null, I get this warning every single time 'Warning: Permanently added '10.9.8.7' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.' Any way to turn that off?

Comment: FYI, you can use * as a wildcard for any number of characters in hostnames or IP addresses. ? represents a single character. So 192.168.* matches 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255 and 192.168.0.? matches 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.9. Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: Unfortunately, when I add the `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' to my config file, it starts asking for my password.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you're using OpenSSH, I believe you can set the

```
CheckHostIP no
```

option to prevent host IPs from being checked in known_hosts.  From the man page:

> CheckHostIP
>
> If this flag is set to 'yes', ssh(1)
>   will additionally check the host IP
>   address in the known_hosts file.  This
>   allows ssh to detect if a host key
>   changed due to DNS spoofing.  If the
>   option is set to 'no', the check will
>   not be executed.  The default is
>   'yes'.

Comment: I've added a section to the bottom of the config file with host 10.0.0.* and below that I put CheckHostIP no 

Do you know if I need to put all the other settings in there or if this is in addition to the * host above?  

I'll have to wait until I log into a system that has been issued a "used" ip address to make sure this change works.  I'll accept your answer if that works.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem this does the trick 100% ... not sure why, I'll have to play with it a bit more and see if I can get it to do what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "100%"? Does it work sometimes but not others?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I never saw your reply.  Because the IP addresses change so frequently and I don't know which I have cached or which I have flushed the file since I last connected to so it was hit or miss.  Eventually more miss than hit.  I just got another suggestion saying to just point my UserKnownHostsFile at /dev/null.  I'm going to try that trick.

Comment: As explained by the man excerpt, option `CheckHostIP` just **additionally** checks the host IP address (rather than **just** check the FQDN). This is also proved by a simple successfull SSH connection with `-oCheckHostIP=no` which adds host to the known file. Use `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null` for desired result.

Answer (score 8):

This took me a while to find. The most common use-case I've seen is when you've got SSH tunnels to remote networks. All the solutions here produced warnings which broke my Nagios scripts.

The option I needed was:

```
NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes
```

Which, as the name suggests also only applies to localhost.

Answer (score 5):

1. Edit your ~/.ssh/config

`nano ~/.ssh/config` (if there wasn't one already, don't worry, nano will create a new file)

2. Add the following config:

```
Host 192.168.*
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable this temporarily or without needing to change your SSH configuration files, you can use:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null username@hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

Since every other answer explains how to disable the key checking, here are two ideas that preserve the key checking, but avoid the problem:

1. Use hostnames. This is easy if you control the DHCP server and can assign proper names. After that you can just use the known hostnames, the changing ips don't matter.
2. Use hostnames. Even if you don't control the DHCP server, you can use a service like `avahi`, which will broadcast the name of the server in our local network. It takes care of solving collisions and other issues.
3. Use host key signing. After you built a machine, sign it with a local CA (you don't need a global trusted CA for that). After that, you don't need to trust each host separately on your machine. It's enough that you trust the signing CA in the known_hosts file. More information in the `ssh-keygen` man page or at many blog posts (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu)